# Ĉu eble diri, kaj estos tio komprena, "levilejo" anstataŭ "lifto"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Vorto "lifto" estas el latina "elevare", kio signifas "levi". Levilo estas io, kio povas levi ion. Tiam levilejo estos ejo, kia povas levi?
Aŭ bonegota vorto "levejo"?

Answer (score 3):

El la *Fundamenta* verbo "levi" oni kompreneble povas derivi substantivojn "levilo" kaj "levilejo". Dum la unuaj tempoj oni certe uzis tiajn derivaĵojn por priskribi diversspecajn ilojn, kiujn oni uzis por levi. Nuntempe multaj derivitaj vortoj havas establiĝintan sencon. Eble la plej konata estas la vorto "malsanulejo", kiu ne plu estas iu ajn loko por malsanaj homoj, sed kuraca institucio, kiu estas parto de san-sistemo.

Do la vorto "levilo" minimume nuntempe unusence signifas [stangon](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levilo), per kiu oni utilas fizikan momanton por pliigi mekanikan forton (angle *lever*, germane *Hebel*, finne *vipu*).

Logike la vorto "levejo" estus loko por levi kaj "levilejo" loko por leviloj, sed verŝajne ambaŭ estas tiel specifaj, ke oni ne ekuzis la vortojn, estis neniu bezono. Konsekvence oni trovas neniom da trafoj de ambaŭ vortoj en [Tekstaro](https://tekstaro.com).

Por priskribi specialan aparaton por mallevi aĵojn kaj pasaĝerojn en vertikala ŝakto en konstruaĵoj oni prunteprenis la anglan vorton kaj kreis la vorton "lifto".

Answer (score 0):

`levilejo` estus ejo, kie troviĝas leviloj (kio ajn tio estas, povus temi pri `lifto`). En tiaj okazoj indas pensi pri simile konstruitaj jamaj vortoj, kiel `kuracilejo` (ia apoteko), `veturilejo` (ebla garaĝo), `armilejo`, ...

Pri `levejo`; ne ĉiuj elementoj logike kunmeteblas, ekzemple la signifo de `movejo` ne estas klara (tio estas, vi *povus* trovi signifon, sed ĝi ne estos tuj aŭ evidente komprenebla de ĉiuj, do lingvanoj ne uzas tiun kunmetaĵon).

Pli da informo pri la pluraj signifoj de `-ej-` oni povas legi [en PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/vortfarado/afiksoj/sufiksoj/ej.html).